# Setting HTTP_REFERER does not work in before hook of RSpec config

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I saw various versions of how to setup a global HTTP_REFERER in RSpec, but none of them worked with RSpec 2.6.4:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, :type => :controller) do
    request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = root_url
  end
end
```

The request is always nil:

```
undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
```

RSpec is calling this:

```
def self.eval_before_eachs(example)
  world.run_hook_filtered(:before, :each, self, example.example_group_instance, example)
  ancestors.reverse.each { |ancestor| ancestor.run_hook(:before, :each, example.example_group_instance) }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# spec/support/http_referer.rb  
module HttpReferer
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      setup :setup_http_referer if respond_to?(:setup)
    end
  end

  def setup_http_referer
    @request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = "/back"
  end
end

# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include HttpReferer, :type => :controller
end
```

Comment: i changed it slightly to `@request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = root_url if @request`

Answer (score 1):

This link may help get you pointed in the right direction...

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29

You'll need to make a module like...

```
module Foo
  def set_referer
    @request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = root_url
  end
end
```

Then configure RSpec...

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.extend Foo, :type => :controller
end
```

Then call it in each of your controller specs...

```
describe MyController do
  set_referer
end
```

We're using a similar approach to set our session cookie, but YMMV.

Comment: that's not the way i was looking for, since i need to call it in every example, which kinda sucks